# How to know if Flatlist is showing blank space while doing a batch rendering?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a long list of items to be displayed on Flatlist, so I had to do some optimisation based on the [Optimizing Flatlst Config doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration). This results in the Flatlist showing blank areas to users sometimes when they scroll too fast.

My question is, is there any method for us to know for sure that the Flatlist is now showing blank area, and when do we know when it has completed the next batch rendering? Would like a reliable way of measuring the occurrence of blank areas for us to find the optimal configurations for the Flatlist.

Comment: not sure, but this might be of some help https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30636#issuecomment-863209382

Comment: Thanks for the link. In my case it's not a must to completely get rid of the blank space as we've accepted that its a trade off for large and complex list. As long as the item eventually renders to user it should be okay. We're just interested to know how often the blank space occurs for user and how long was the period of blank so that we can continuously adjust the config for Flatlist.